# Maintain controller state in Angular like Durandal does?

Tags: angularjs, durandal

I like that Durandal has Activate/Deactivate methods that get called on the VM and that the views can even be cached.

Is there a way to have this same features in Angular?

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit more, for those who are not familiar with Durandal and its methods?

Comment: @Stewie - When durandal activates a route the matching ViewModel will have several methods called on it if they exist.  ViewAttached, Activate and Deactivate are just a few of them that I have found to be very useful.  After navigating to a new route durandal can keep the prev. VM reference alive so that navigating back will the VM will not have to reload all of its state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service / factory. These are singletons in AngularJS and you can inject them to the controller. Strictly have one service per controller and the service will be maintained between navigations to the view / controller.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

The way this would work is that your controller would take `myService` as an injected dependency. Then you assign it to $scope as `$scope.cache = myService`. Then in your view you bind to `cache.someProperty` for elements that wanted cached.

***Just as an aside:***

You can even share services containing state data between controllers. Although I would recommend against this pattern, because it looks like global state. Services you share between controllers should ideally only provide functionality instead of being data objects. Unless you are specifically looking for a global data store :)

Comment: What method would you recommend then?

Comment: @MaxWillmo made answer more explicit :)

Comment: So when my controller loads again I would have to pull all my saved state from the from the service and reassign it to $scope ?  Seems like I should maybe use $cacheFactory instead??  Is there any kind of deactivate that gets called on the controller so that I know when to save my state?

Comment: @Tyler added clarification to answer : The way this would work is that your controller would take `myService` as an injected dependency. Then you assign it to $scope as `$scope.cache = myService`. Then in your view you bind to `cache.someProperty` for elements that wanted cached.

Comment: I prefer the usage of global state, here is my solution for this: http://lifeinide.blogspot.com/2014/05/global-state-in-angularjs-controllers.html